# slow down the viewpager

Tags: android, image, timer, android-viewpager

i set group of images in view pager i want the images to scroll automatically but in slow motion . my problem is the images move very fast how to solve that how to do that in my code
pager adapter`

```
public class CustomerAdapter extends PagerAdapter {
//private int[] images = {R.mipmap.img1,R.mipmap.img2,R.mipmap.img3,R.mipmap.img4};
private Context ctx;
private  String[] urls;
private LayoutInflater inflater;
final Handler handler = new Handler();
public Timer swipeTimer ;

public CustomerAdapter(Context ctx,String []urls){
    this.ctx = ctx;
    this.urls=urls;
}
@Override
public int getCount() {
    return urls.length;
}

@Override
public boolean isViewFromObject(View view, Object object) {
    return (view ==(LinearLayout)object);
}

@Override
public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, int position) {
    inflater = (LayoutInflater)ctx.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.swip,container,false);
    ImageView img =(ImageView)v.findViewById(R.id.itemview);

    Picasso.with(ctx).load(urls[position]).into(img);


    container.addView(v);
    return v;
}

@Override
public void destroyItem(View container, int position, Object object) {
    container.refreshDrawableState();
}
public void setTimer(final ViewPager myPager, int time, final int numPages, final int curPage){

    final Runnable Update = new Runnable() {
        int NUM_PAGES =numPages;
        int currentPage = curPage ;
        public void run() {
            if (currentPage == NUM_PAGES ) {
                currentPage = 0;
            }
            myPager.setCurrentItem(currentPage++, true);
        }
    };

    swipeTimer = new Timer();
    swipeTimer.schedule(new TimerTask() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            handler.post(Update);
        }
    }, 1000, time*1000);

}
public void stopTimer(){
    //handler.removeCallbacks(null);
    swipeTimer.cancel();
}
}
```

in my mainpage

```
 ViewPager viewPager =  (ViewPager)convertView.findViewById(R.id.view_pager);
    adapter = new CustomerAdapter(getContext(),imagesfortest);
    viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
    viewPager.setCurrentItem(0);
    adapter.setTimer(viewPager,5000,4,imagesfortest.length);
```

Answer (score 0):

Set Transformation. [Reference](https://developer.android.com/training/animation/screen-slide.html#pagetransformer)

```
mPager.setPageTransformer(true, new ZoomOutPageTransformer());
```

then customize transform animation.

Comment: it helped me to fade in and out when the images moved but still they move very quickly

Comment: yes thats the animation. so you can control it do to whatever you want. the fade or zoom is just sample.